# Python error according to float and string

Tags: python

my code:

```
total = total + array[idx]
```

I got this error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

how do I fix this error?

Comment: Take a giant step back and consider for a moment the question of whether or not data-types should implicitly place nicely with one another

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to mathematically add a string to a float. You should first cast the string to a float:

```
total = total + float(array[idx])
```

Comment: hey tim, thanks for your answer, I tried that and it gave me back another error. It says: total = total + float(array[idx])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: C

Comment: It would help if you explained a bit what are you trying to achieve with your code. I supposed you were accumulating numbers, but it seems your array contains strings. Are you trying to concatenate letters?

Comment: I'm doing a project in computer programming course for economists.

Comment: #read a csv line and convert to list
def read_csv_line(line):
    res = []
    parts = line.split(',')
    for i in range(len(parts)):
        res.append(parts[i])

    return res

Comment: this is the first part, the second part is:

Comment: #read a csv file and convert to multi-list
def read_csv(path):
    res = []
    f = open(path)
    #Handle first row
    res.append(f.readline().rstrip().split(','))
    for line in f:
        res.append(read_csv_line(line.rstrip()))
    f.close()
    return res

Comment: the third part:

#this function as a variable recieves a single dimensioned list and returns its average  
def calc_avg(array):
    total = 0.0
    for idx in range(len(array)):
        total = total + float(array[idx])
    
    return total/len(array)

Comment: Stop, please post the code in the original question

Comment: Please edit your question and add your full code. That would help a lot.

Comment: listen, I have a csv file(xcel) that is a table which includes: date, rate. I need python to read from this file the numbers from a string function to float so when I run the module it will be able to read and return numbers(the average). I already wrote the code, I just need to convert the first and second part to float.

Comment: The second error message you got is caused because you are trying to convert a 'C' into a float, which is not possible. Check that you are reading the correct columns/rows and that the content of your array are float values.

Comment: what do you mean by a "C"?

Comment: `float(array[idx])` tried to convert the value stored in `array[idx]` to a float, but it found a string with the character 'C', which cannot be converted to a float. So the problem in your code seems to be that you are not storing the correct data in your array.

Comment: now it doesn't show me any error. I found out that C is where the csv file is placed. But now when I try running the module, the python shell shows me nothing

Comment: This probably calls for a new and different question, then. Also, I'm sorry but without your full code I find it difficult to help you any further.

Comment: if you want I can send you my full code to your email address. what's your email?

Comment: This is not how stackoverflow works. You should post your code in the question where it is helpful for the community, and also, that way maybe more people can help you.

Comment: #read a csv line and convert to list
def read_csv_line(line):
    res = []
    parts = line.split(',')
    for i in range(len(parts)):
        res.append(parts[i])

    return res

Comment: #read a csv file and convert to multi-list
def read_csv(path):
    res = []
    f = open(path)
    #Handle first row
    res.append(f.readline().rstrip().split(','))
    for line in f:
        res.append(read_csv_line(line.rstrip()))
    f.close()
    return res

Comment: #this function as a variable recieves a single dimensioned list and returns its average  
def calc_avg(array):
    total = 0.0
    for idx in range(len(array)):
        total = total + float(array[idx])
    
    return total/len(array)


x = read_csv("C:\\Users\galDaking\Desktop\Python\input_file.csv")
print x

Comment: this is my full code. when I run the module, why isn't python shell showing me the csv average of my csv file stored in C://?